# Retrofit2/ Gson null values are not skipped when DEFAULT_SERIALIZE_NULLS value is used

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I am running into some unknown error. This breaks my assumption of null-safety with Kotlin data class and Api responses.

Say, I have a data class say `Person`:

```
 data class Person(val name: String) {
    constructor() : this("")
}
```

This will generate an object Person with default name value i.e. non-null.
Earlier, When I use a default retrofit client with `GsonConverterFactory.create()` (added as a converter factory). In default mode, Gson doesn't serialize a null value. But today I found out that field is getting serialized to null.

I verfiy the same in `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java#L206

Here the [instance](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java#L212) value is having non-null field but after reading each field (`field.read(in, instance);`) it is assigning the null value.
I am expecting the null values to be skipped during serialization or is it deserialization?

---

Edit:
Looks like it is deserializing nulls not serializing null problem.
Reference: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1148

Let me know if any detail missing or creating confusion.

Comment: Can you post related JSON?

Comment: It's a sample data class only. It looks like during deserialization null values are not skipped when using default gson converter.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make name parameter nullable by changing type;

```
String
```

to

```
String?
```